# Nifty counter in precompiled header does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers, static-initialization, stdafx.h

To fix a problem caused by the [static (de-)initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#nifty-counter-idiom) I tried to use the [Nifty Counter idiom aka Schwartz Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter). I noticed, however, that it does not work if the header file containing the static initializer is included inside Visual Studio's precompiled header. In such a case I see in the debugger, that the constructor of the static initializer is called **after** the constructor of the other static object.

If I declare an additional static initializer right after `#include "stdafx.h"` or edit the precompiled header to not contain the declaration it works as expected.

Any ideas what might cause this?

**EDIT**

---

I was finally able to reproduce this problem in a new dummy project:

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Foo.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef NIFTY
static int SchwartzCounter; // zero initialized at load time
static typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Foo), alignof (Foo)>::type foo_buf;

Foo& foo = reinterpret_cast<Foo&>(foo_buf);
#else
Foo foo;
#endif

Foo::Foo()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
}

void Foo::doSomething()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    assert(x == 42);
}

#ifdef NIFTY
FooInitializer::FooInitializer()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;

    if (SchwartzCounter++ == 0)
    {
        new (&foo) Foo();
    }
}

FooInitializer::~FooInitializer()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;

    if (--SchwartzCounter == 0)
    {
        (&foo)->~Foo();
    }
}
#endif
```

**Foo.h**

```
#pragma once
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    void doSomething();

private:
    int x = 42;
};

#ifdef NIFTY
extern Foo& foo;

static struct FooInitializer {
    FooInitializer();
    ~FooInitializer();
} fooInitializer;
#else
extern Foo foo;
#endif
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef NIFTY
static int SchwartzCounter; // zero initialized at load time
static typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Bar), alignof (Bar)>::type bar_buf;

Bar& bar = reinterpret_cast<Bar&>(bar_buf);
#else
Bar bar;
#endif

Bar::Bar()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    foo.doSomething();
}

Bar::~Bar()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
}

void Bar::doSomething()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    assert(x == 42);
}

#ifdef NIFTY
BarInitializer::BarInitializer()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;

    if (SchwartzCounter++ == 0)
    {
        new (&bar) Bar();
    }
}

BarInitializer::~BarInitializer()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;

    if (--SchwartzCounter == 0)
    {
        (&bar)->~Bar();
    }
}
#endif
```

**Bar.h**

```
#pragma once
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    ~Bar();

    void doSomething();

private:
    int x = 42;
};

#ifdef NIFTY
extern Bar& bar;

static struct BarInitializer {
    BarInitializer();
    ~BarInitializer();
} barInitializer;
#else
extern Bar bar;
#endif
```

**stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// If the following define is commented out, the nifty counter idiom is not used
#define NIFTY

// If the following include is commented out while the nifty counter idiom is used, the initialization order is correct
#include "Foo.h"
```

Comment: It is probably caused by incorrect implementation of such counter in your code. Otherwise all the default vs projects won't be able to deal with `cout` `cerr` `cin` that are utilizing such a counter. You should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the stated issue. What does "does not work" even mean?

Comment: @VTT -- the Microsoft C++ library doesn't use the nifty counter to initialize the standard stream objects. It uses a Microsoft-specific compiler hook.

Comment: @VTT Thanks for your comment. I was finally able to reproduce the problem and added a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example demonstrating the stated issue

Comment: Seems like a compiler (or likely linker) bug indeed. You may want to report it.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with VS2019, version 16.7.7. Can anyone confirm that this actually works with other compilers? Where you able to solve your problem, @sigy? If so, how?

Comment: I filed a bug report for VS, see [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Schwarz-counter-vs-precompiled-header/1256884). Please upvote and let's see what they make of it.